# Template specialization for all wide character types

Tags: c++, templates

i want to improve my knowledge in c++ templates at the moment and i came across a problem. Is it possible to write a template function which accepts all wide character types like std::wstring, wchar_t, wchar_t* and so on? Here is an example to show what i mean:

```
template <typename T> Function(T1 var)
{
    // Do something with std::stringstream and the passed var;
}
```

The problem with the function above is that it doesnt work with wchar_t or std::wstring for example. You need to use std::wstringstream instead. I could specialize now like:

```
template <> Function(wchar_t var)
{
    // Do something with std::wstringstream and the passed var;
}
```

Now i would have to write the same function for each wide string type, but is it possible to specialize once and cover all wide string types?

Thx in advance!

Comment: Of course that first function works with all the types. The problem is that you don't show the code, and I guess you have some static types declared there. Show us your desired implementation of the function

Comment: You could probably just use `std::basic_stringstream` with a template argument that depends on a template parameter. `std::stringstream` is actually `std::basic_stringstream<char>` and `std::wstringstream` is `std::basic_stringstream<wchar_t>`.

Comment: `wchar_t` and `wchar_t*` are two different things. I'm not quite sure what your function is supposed to do...

Comment: @KerrekSB: The question makes sense if you imagine the body of the question as `std::cout << var;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use traits technique. Define some `is_wide_char_type` class template. Like this:

```
template <T>
struct is_wide_char_type { static const bool VALUE = false; };
template <>
struct is_wide_char_type<wchar_t> { static const bool VALUE = TRUE; };
... for others types the same.
```

Then specialize your function for two versions, you need to define class template because function template cannot be partially specialized:

```
template <typename T, boo isWideChar> class FunctionImpl;
template <typename T> struct FunctionImpl<T, false> {
  static void doIt() {
     // code for not wide char types
  }
};
template <typename T> struct FunctionImpl<T, true> {
  static void doIt() {
     // code for wide char types
  }
};


template <typename T> Function(T1 var)
{
   FunctionImpl<T, is_wide_char_type<T>::VALUE>::doIt();
}
```

OR consider to make it even easier and enclose in traits `is_wide_char_type<T>` not the just tag information of kind of `T` but also about which stringstream to use and whatever you like.

Comment: Thank you PiotrNycz thats exactly what I was looking for! The funny thing is i almost came to your solution but i didnt know that functions cant be partially specialized and that i need to use classes instead. Thanks!

Comment: With tag dispatching (See http://www.boost.org/community/generic_programming.html#traits) it could be achieved with overloaded functions only. I just consider the solution with partially specialized classes as easier, but feel free to try tag dispatching. To achieve this you'll need to define two tag structs (one per kind) and use it in is_Wide_char_type.

Comment: Ok, i tested your solution today and it works fine. The only problem are wchar_t arrays now. When I pass a wchar_t[3] for example i have to cast to wchar_t* because i cant find a version of is_wide_char_type<T> for variable array sizes. But everything else works fine.

Comment: Try explicit template parameter: `Function<wchar_t[3]>();`. For definition use `template <size_t N>
struct is_wide_char_type<wchar_t[N]> { static const bool VALUE = TRUE; };`. AFAIK - this should work. With implicit template parameter - the pointer interpretation of array always will be seletected :(